# Calculate top 10 watched URLs with daily and weekly averages

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a long list of URL watched history stored in a table that has the following attributes:

Timestamp : timestamp when ad was watched

Category  : the URL category, strings such as 'Home', 'Images', etc

URL       : the URL

Duration  : how long it took to service the URL.

There are multiple records for each URL

I need to come up with an output that lists the following for the top 10 watched URLs in each Category:

```
URL       Category       Last Days Average Duration    Last Weeks Average Duration
```

Ideally I would prefer not creating a function/trigger. I am researching CTEs and Grouping Sets.

Some sample data would be:

```
2017-03-01,'Home','www.url.com/home.php',50
2017-03-03,'Images','www.img.com/image.jpg',70
2017-03-01,'Home','www.net.com/home.php',60
2017-03-10,'Home','www.url.com/home.php',50
```

Sample output could be:

Top 10 URL's with Category and Last Day's and Last Week's Average

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `DENSE_RANK()` window function for descending rank order of *Category* by *Duration*. By the way, this is a very common SQL question even having its own tag, [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/greatest-n-per-group/info).

```
SELECT main.*
FROM
  (SELECT t.Timestamp, t.Category, t.URL, t.Duration,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Category ORDER BY t.Duration DESC) AS 'Rank'
   FROM myTable t) AS main
WHERE main.Rank <= 10
```

And for SQL databases without window functions (in case you ever migrate platforms), use the count correlated subquery which works in all RDBMS's albeit not most efficient. However, below replicates `RANK` not `DENSE_RANK`.

```
SELECT main.*
FROM
  (SELECT t.Timestamp, t.Category, t.URL, t.Duration,
          (SELECT Count(*) FROM mytable sub 
           WHERE sub.Category = t.Category AND sub.Duration >= t.Duration) AS Rank
   FROM myTable t) AS main
WHERE main.Rank <= 10
```